# PHP $_Session and $_GET variables to extract data from database based on links

Tags: php, sql, session

I am a beginner in PHP and i am currently working on making an online youth mentorship portal for my project. What my system will basically do is ask mentors and mentees to sign up. Mentors will pick the categories in which they wish to mentor in. Once mentees login, they will be redirected to a page with the list of categories available for mentorship. What i'm having a problem in is extracting data from the database based on what category the mentee clicks on. I'm sorry for being so daft but i'm a rookie and i've traversed the net but to no avail.

Here is my categoryindex.php page:

```html
<h2>Choose the category you want to be mentored in:</h2><br><br>

<li><a href="script.php?category=Music">Music</a></li><br>
<li><a href="script.php?category=ICT">ICT</a></li><br>
<li><a href="script.php?category=Politics">Politics</a></li><br>
<li><a href="script.php?category=Entrepreneurship">Entrepreneurship</a></li><br>
<li><a href="script.php?category=Sports">Sports</a></li><br>
<li><a href="script.php?category=Religious">Religious</a></li><br>
<li><a href="script.php?category=Agriculture">Agriculture</a></li><br>
<li><a href="script.php?category=Finance">Finance & Banking</a></li><br>
<li><a href="script.php?category=Leadership">Leadership</a></li><br>
<li><a href="script.php?category=Science">Science</a></li><br>
<li><a href="script.php?category=Fashion">Fashion/Beauty</a></li><br>
<li><a href="script.php?category=Medical">Medical</a></li>
```

Here is my script.php page(can't understand how to reference the "where category=" part:

```
<?php
require('db.php');
session_start();
$_SESSION['selected_category']-> $_GET['category'];
mysqli_select_db($con,'ymp');
$query = "SELECT * FROM mentor WHERE category =?";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("Failed to query database" . mysqli_error($con));
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
```

Kindly help me out. Thank you

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If I understand well, you should see this : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php how prepare statement and bind param

Comment: And I'm not sure about this `$_SESSION['selected_category']-> $_GET['category'];`, where is the category? If the category is in your URL eg. `www.my-website/my-page&category=music` you just need `$category = $_GET['category']` (= "music" here).

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the question-mark with a value, in this case the $_GET['category'] variable.

Best practice is to use prepared statements:

```
<?php
  require('db.php');

  session_start();

  $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM mentor WHERE category = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['category']);
  $stmt->execute();

  $res = $stmt->get_result();
  $row = $res->num_rows;

?>
```

If you don't declare this value, the query won't run.

Hope this helps, if not just ask and I could take another look at your code!

Comment: Not safe to SQL injection. Should use prepared statements there.

Comment: Nope, real_escape_string is better than nothing but not exactly what's called fine nowadays. Use prepared statements. Always.

Comment: @jonas3344 changed the answer to use prepared statements as well, I agree that real_escape_string is a bad solution, but I thought it was easier for him. Better to learn prepared_statements however.

Comment: @Julian Yes, that's much better. :)